# Почему возникает странная ошибка при создании двух EntityManagers?

Tags: php, symfony

собственно вот настройки doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
           ...
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                logging: false
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                options:
                    1002: 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""))'
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            push:
                driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
                path: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_PUSH)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            push:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: push
                mappings:
                    Push:
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Push/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Push\Entity'
                        alias: Push
                        is_bundle: false
```

делаю так

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --allow-empty-diff --no-interaction --em=default
```

получаю ошибку

```
The class 'App\Push\Entity\Message' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model
```

делаю так

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --allow-empty-diff --no-interaction --em=push
```

получаю

```
The class 'App\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Push\Entity
```

что я делаю не так и как правильно ?